# Navigate to a specific module in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I use PyCharm as my IDE for working with Django. So far, it's navigation shortcuts have proven very useful. I can go to a specific (project) file with `Ctrl+Shift+N`, I can go to any class definition with `Ctrl+N` and can go to any symbol with `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+N`.

This is great, but lately I've seen that it would be very useful too to have a shortcut to move to a specific external (or project) module.

Is there any shortcut where I can pass for example: `django.contrib` and show the modules for inside `django.contrib` package or `base64` and show me the modules match for `base64`, just as easy as I can go to a specific, symbol, class, file?

Comment: `from django.contrib import` then hit ctrl+space  ? not sure if thats what you are asking ... also I use f3 to jump to any definition ///  maybe just different keybinding?

Comment: Not exactly, `ctrl+space` give me autocompletion. What I'm asking is a way to go directly to `django.contrib.auth` module by just typing `django.contrib.auth` directly.

Comment: You can `ctrl+click` to view the declaration.

Comment: In fact, that gives me an idea. When I wanted to go to a module, i'll just write it and then `ctrl+click`. Thanks, but still, there should be around a better way to do this, _a shorter shortcut_ maybe doesn't exist out of the box in PyCharm. I guess it might be a good idea for a plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I feel your problem. All you have to do is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + CLICK on the definition. Please note, however that this does not provide the *actual* files. What I mean by this is that it does not re-direct you to the actual function, but rather a skeleton of the function.

If you want to go to the actual function, you will need to go it it my clicking on external libraries on your sidebar and do a search.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is the way I'm doing it indeed. Just wanted to know if PyCharm got this tool built-in, a little more natively, without doing it with ctrl+click trick.